# Same mesh with different cloth properties

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make clothing for a character, specifically a wool jersey in which the neck, hip, and wrists have sort of a thick wool ring, and I wanted those to have different cloth properties so that they were more stiff than the rest of the clothing.
If it wasn't clear enough, I'm talking about the element below the strips, the one that surrounds the shoulders.

[image: A ref of the character]

[image: Where I'm at right now]

Comment: You can use vertex groups to control stiffness (I believe the Structural Group is where you'd use it). If not use two different objects (with different settings for the cloth) and parent them.